# Does the Linux Genreic Block Layer prefer Read requests over Write Requests?

Tags: linux-kernel, block-device, scheduling, bios

Does the Generic Block Layer in the Linux kernel, prioritize read requests over write requests ?

That is without taking the I/O scheduler into account.